# How to change color of pdf icons in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I export SF Symbols to pdf icons and default white color changed to black.
I would like to change the black color back to white.
I found that `.colorInvert` do it but when I put `Image` into `Button` it set black again.

```swift
import SwiftUI

#if os(macOS)
extension Image {
    static func sfSymbol(_ systemName: String) -> some View {
        Image(systemName)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .colorInvert()
        .frame(height: 20)
    }
}

struct ImageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            Image.sfSymbol("square.and.arrow.down.fill")
            Button(action: {}, label: { Image.sfSymbol("square.and.arrow.down.fill") })
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

PDF icon: [square.and.arrow.down.fill.imageset](https://github.com/filimo/ReaderTranslator/tree/master/ReaderTranslatorMac/Assets.xcassets/square.and.arrow.down.fill.imageset)

[image]

Comment: I see no issues. Please upload a sample project and place a link here.

Comment: You can reproduce this issue with above code.  [square.and.arrow.down.fill.imageset](https://github.com/filimo/ReaderTranslator/tree/master/ReaderTranslatorMac/Assets.xcassets/square.and.arrow.down.fill.imageset)

Comment: Thats a lot! can you please upload a minimal version? Just one view!

Comment: You can run my project if you need. https://github.com/filimo/ReaderTranslator.git
There are many views there. 
You should select ReaderTranslatorMac target and go to
[https://github.com/filimo/ReaderTranslator/blob/master/ReaderTranslator/Extentions/Image.swift](https://github.com/filimo/ReaderTranslator/blob/master/ReaderTranslator/Extentions/Image.swift)

Comment: Try to make it rendred as Template Image instead of Original, by changing the rendering mode to .alwaysTemplate.

Comment: .alwaysTemplate is available for UIImage only not for Image in SwiftUI

Comment: For the solution check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59974025/4145420

Answer (score 7):

I actually had the same problem and figured out that you have to change the rendering mode in the icon's attribute inspector to "Template Image".

Comment: this is the solution

Comment: this should accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Here is the solution:

```
Image(systemName)
    .renderingMode(.template)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
```

Link to the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59974025/4145420).

Enjoy.